# gawk: Using a combination of "/proc/net/route" and "/proc/net/fib_trie" to determine the current local IP address

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sh, tmux

I would like to create a **gawk-one-command-only** solution[1], which `determines the current local IP address` via `/proc/net/route` and `/proc/net/fib_trie`.

I would like to use the `first octett` of the `gateway` value from `/proc/net/route` (`0xC0` (`192`)) as pattern; only, if the first octett is greater than `0`:

```
$ < "/proc/net/route"
Iface   Destination     Gateway         Flags   RefCnt  Use     Metric  Mask            MTU     Window  IRTT
enp3s0  00000000        0100A8C0        0003    0       0       0       00000000        0       0       0
enp3s0  00000000        00000000        0001    0       0       1000002 00000000        0       0       0
enp3s0  0000FEA9        00000000        0001    0       0       2       0000FFFF        0       0       0
enp3s0  0000A8C0        00000000        0001    0       0       0       00FFFFFF        0       0       0
```

The following command returns `0xC0`:

```bash
$ gawk 'NR >= 2 \
{ \
    if($3 > 0) \
        print "0x"substr($3, length($3)-1, length($3)) \
}' "/proc/net/route"
0xC0
```

Which can be used to `convert` it to a `decimal number`:

```bash
$ gawk 'NR >= 2 \
{ \
    if($3 > 0) \
        print strtonum("0x"substr($3, length($3)-1, length($3))) \
}' "/proc/net/route"
192
```

The function `strtonum()` converts the `hex number`.

The following command for `/proc/net/fib_trie` returns me these values:

```bash
$ gawk '/32 host/ { print f } { f=$2 }' "/proc/net/fib_trie"
127.0.0.1
169.254.88.86
192.168.1.80
127.0.0.1
169.254.88.86
192.168.1.80
```

```
Main:
  +-- 0.0.0.0/0 3 0 4
     |-- 0.0.0.0
        /0 universe UNICAST
        /0 link UNICAST
     +-- 127.0.0.0/8 2 0 2
        +-- 127.0.0.0/31 1 0 0
           |-- 127.0.0.0
              /8 host LOCAL
           |-- 127.0.0.1
              /32 host LOCAL
        |-- 127.255.255.255
           /32 link BROADCAST
     +-- 169.254.0.0/16 2 0 1
        |-- 169.254.0.0
           /16 link UNICAST
        |-- 169.254.88.86
           /32 host LOCAL
        |-- 169.254.255.255
           /32 link BROADCAST
     +-- 192.168.0.0/24 2 1 2
        +-- 192.168.0.0/26 2 0 2
           |-- 192.168.0.0
              /24 link UNICAST
           |-- 192.168.1.80
              /32 host LOCAL
        |-- 192.168.0.255
           /32 link BROADCAST
Local:
  +-- 0.0.0.0/0 3 0 4
     |-- 0.0.0.0
        /0 universe UNICAST
        /0 link UNICAST
     +-- 127.0.0.0/8 2 0 2
        +-- 127.0.0.0/31 1 0 0
           |-- 127.0.0.0
              /8 host LOCAL
           |-- 127.0.0.1
              /32 host LOCAL
        |-- 127.255.255.255
           /32 link BROADCAST
     +-- 169.254.0.0/16 2 0 1
        |-- 169.254.0.0
           /16 link UNICAST
        |-- 169.254.88.86
           /32 host LOCAL
        |-- 169.254.255.255
           /32 link BROADCAST
     +-- 192.168.0.0/24 2 1 2
        +-- 192.168.0.0/26 2 0 2
           |-- 192.168.0.0
              /24 link UNICAST
           |-- 192.168.1.80
              /32 host LOCAL
        |-- 192.168.0.255
           /32 link BROADCAST
```

I thought of something like the following: Combine the above three commands as one `gawk` command and filter the local IP address from `/proc/net/fib_trie`:

```bash
$ gawk '/32 host/ && /strtonum(0xC0)/ { print f; <do_an_awk_sort_--unique_equivalent_somewhere_in_between_for_192.168.1.80> } { f=$2 }' "/proc/net/fib_trie"
192.168.1.80
```

I cannot think of any proper solution right now.

Thanks!

---

[1]
Background story:

I am using `tmux` and want to output the current local IP address, but the [current solution](https://github.com/keks24/dotfiles/blob/master/etc/tmux.conf#L227-L235) forks three subshells: `/bin/sh` with `ip` and `gawk`. I would like to have a `gawk`-only-solution for this to have less load on the CPU.

Solving this leads to another solution, where I can combine this with another `gawk` command, where I calculate the [current uptime](https://github.com/keks24/dotfiles/blob/master/etc/tmux.conf#L216-L226).

My ultimate goal is to only depend on `procfs` and `sysfs` and have only **two** `gawk` commands, which will represent the following status bar of `tmux`:

[`tmux` status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtSBo.png)

In [this example](https://github.com/keks24/dotfiles/blob/master/etc/tmux.conf#L138-L196) I have already done that for the `left hand side`.

I hope, I explained everything elaborately enough to this very late hour.

Thank you!

-Ramon

Comment: please update the question with the contents of your `/proc/net/fib_trie`, making sure to point out which line(s) you're looking to match on as well as the expected output

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using `ip addr`? Then you could just do something like `ip addr | awk '/ether/{target=1; next} target && $1 == "inet" {print $2; exit}'`

Comment: @markp-fuso, is this better? :)

@DavidC.Rankin, I am already doing this with `ip --oneline -family inet route get 1 | gawk [...]`, but I want to avoid using `ip` and only have the dependency to `procfs` and `gawk`.

Comment: still looking for a copy of your `/proc/net/fib/trie`; also, please verify you want to match on any ip tuple (not just the 1st tuple) that could match on `192`? what kind of `sort` are you looking for ... string sort? numeric sort? version sort? what would be the expected output if you have 2 matches: `123.100.192.1` and `192.168.1.80`?

Comment: while your sample `/proc/net/route` only has a single row that matches your `awk` conditional, it's not clear what we're supposed to do if there are 2 (or more) rows from `/proc/net/route` that match your `awk` conditional ... use the 1st value we find? use the smallest (largest) value? process all values?

Comment: @markp-fuso, I misread your first comment. I have provided the content now. The result should be `192.168.1.80`, so using the `first three octets` of the gateway IP address would be sufficient to match against it. If there are multiple matches with `192.168.1.80`, it should be grouped to one like `sort --unique` does. I guess, just using the first value from `/proc/net/route` would be fine. I am going to look for more contents of `/proc/net/route` and `/proc/net/fib_trie`. Maybe I can explain preciser then.

Answer (score 1):

One idea for a consolidated `awk` script:

```
awk '

# FNR==NR ==> 1st file (route)

FNR==NR { if (FNR>1 && $3>0) {
             len=length($3)
             octett=strtonum("0x" substr($3,len-1))       # convert last hex to decimal
             nextfile                                     # skip to next file; assumes (for now) we are only interested in first octett we find
          }
          next                                            # skip to next record
        }

# FNR!=NR ==> 2nd file (fib_trie)

octett  { if ($0 ~ /32 host/) {                           # if octett is non-zero (ie, we found an octett) and current line matches "32 host" then ...
             split(ip,a,".")                              # split ip into tuples
             for (i=1;i<=4;i++)                           # loop through tuples and ...
                 if (a[i] == octett) {                    # if a tuple == octett then ...
                    iplist[ip]                            # add ip as an iplist[] array index (ie, add ip to our list of ips
                    next                                  # break out of loop and skip to next input line
                 }
          }
          else
             ip=$2                                        # make note of current (potential) ip
        }

# after all input files/records have been processed ...

END     { for (ip in iplist)                              # loop through list of ips and ...
              print ip                                    # print to stdout
        }
' /proc/net/route /proc/net/fib_trie
```

This generates:

```
192.168.1.80
```

**NOTES:**

- There are a few outstanding issues that need to be addressed by OP ...
- What to do if we find more than one non-zero Gateway/octett in `/proc/net/route`?
- What to do if we find more than one ip address (in `proc/net/fib_trie`) with a tuple that matches the octett(s) (from `/proc/net/route`)?
- If we find multiple ip addresses is there a sorting requirement when printing to stdout?

Comment: I appreciate your solution! I will come back, when I got enough time to gather more information and work out my question properly! :)